# extract multiple blocks of text to a new file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I need help extracting blocks of information from a single text file into new files or some form where I can manipulate the data from each block.

Example:

```
[Block1]
this=that
here=there
why=why_not

[Block2]
this=those
here=there
why=because
```

I need to be able to display and/or manipulate the variables (which I can do if I can isolate the right one).  I don't mind writing each one of these blocks to a temp file

So, how would I change `here=there` to `here=anywhere` only in `Block2`?

I've tried to figure this out using sed/awk but no avail.

Comment: What about recombining the blocks afterwards? Is the ordering of blocks important?

Comment: Not for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution using Perl:

```sh
perl -00 -pe '/^\[Block2\]\n/ or next; s/^here=there$/here=anywhere/m'
```

`-p` tells perl to wrap the code in an implicit input/output loop (similar to sed).

`-00` tells perl to process the input in units of paragraphs (instead of lines).

`-e ...` specifies the program. We first make sure the paragraph starts with `[Block2]` (otherwise we skip all other processing). Then we replace a line of the form `here=there` with `here=anywhere`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Not necessarily. Without a filename it'll just read from stdin, so it could be used as part of a pipeline, for example.

Comment: I know that and you know that, but as it is, I'm suggesting OP may not know how to use your answer and it might help to explain a little, because as it is, it will just hang if he runs it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play with that.  I do know how to pass it a filename ;)

Comment: Ok, that works, and I just perl -00 -pi -e .... to edit in place.

Now I'm trying to actually write each of those blocks of code to a separate file.  I'm trying this, but it's not doing what I want:  


`i=1 ; while true; do perl -00 -pe '/^\[Block2\]\n/ or next' input_filename > output_filenames_$i ; let i++ ; done`

Comment: Oh, in this situation, all blocks start with [block]

Answer (score 4):

With sed:

```
sed '/^\[Block2\]/,/^$/s/here=there/here=anywhere/' file
```

- `/^\[Block2\]/,/^$/`: between line starting with `[Block2]` to next blank line(`^$`) or end of file...
- `s/here=there/here=anywhere/`: replace `here=there` with `here=anywhere`

Comment: As `sed` is the indicated tool for block processing, This could be *accepted answer*!!

Comment: What happens if the assumptions about the file format are incorrect. INI files may or may not have spaces before of after the `=` and there may not be a blank file before the next section.

Comment: @RedCricket `s/here *=.*/here=anywhere/`

Answer (score 1):

This will split the file for you into files named block1, block2, etc. and make the changes you need to Block2 and will work with any awk on any UNIX box:

```
awk -v RS= -F'\n' '
{
    close(out)
    out = "block" NR
    if ($1 == "[Block2]") {
        sub(/here=there/,"here=anywhere")
    }
    print > out
}
' file
```

With GNU awk it's even briefer:

```
awk -vRS= -F'\n' '$1=="[Block2]"{sub(/here=there/,"here=anywhere")} {print>("block"NR)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.94/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm) Perl module. If you are running on a RedHat or Centos system try this:

```
$ sudo yum install perl-Config-IniFiles
```

For Ubuntu use `apt-get ...`.

Here's the modified version of the example script from Config::IniFile's synopsis:

```
$ cat syn.pl
#!/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use Config::IniFiles;
my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => "./inifile.ini" );
print "The value is " . $cfg->val( 'Block2', 'here' ) . ".\n"
    if $cfg->val( 'Block2', 'here' );
```

Here's a example run:

```
$ cat inifile.ini
[Block1]
this=that
here=there
why=why_not

[Block2]
this=those
here=there
why=because
$ ./syn.pl
The value is there.
```

Changing `here` in `Block2` is easy:

```
$ cat rewrite.pl
#!/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use Config::IniFiles;
my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => "./inifile.ini" );
print "The value is " . $cfg->val( 'Block2', 'here' ) . ".\n"
    if $cfg->val( 'Block2', 'here' );
$cfg->setval( 'Block2', 'here', 'anywhere' );
$cfg->RewriteConfig();
$ cat inifile.ini
[Block1]
this=that
here=there
why=why_not

[Block2]
this=those
here=there
why=because
$ ./rewrite.pl
The value is there.
$ cat inifile.ini
[Block1]
this=that
here=there
why=why_not

[Block2]
this=those
here=anywhere
why=because
```

Answer (score 0):

First insert "here=anywhere" and then remove doublet.

```
awk '/this=those/{print;print "here=anywhere";next}!($0 in a) {a[$0];print}' file

[Block1]
this=that
here=there
why=why_not

[Block2]
this=those
here=anywhere
why=because
```